# VBA: String (e.g. "35 miles") embedded in cell - how to format cell based on how large the distance is?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, string

Sorry for the title - I don't know quite how to phrase this.

I get a report which locates a person against a destination, and calculates the distance between the two, which is then exported to Excel. On the X-axis is the date, and the Y-Axis has the person. The cell then contains data, as follows:

Destination: EXAMPLE

Latitude: EXAMPLE

Longitude: EXAMPLE

Distance from start point: 35 miles

(and then some more information).

I’d like to use some code that will highlight the cells in different colours based on how far the distance is from the start point. For example, if <40 miles, green, 40-60 miles, yellow, >60 miles, red.

I know how to isolate a text string if I have a specific text, but given that I want to find anything from 1 mile to a few hundred miles, I’m not sure how to code this. The miles also aren't the only numbers in the cell, so I can't isolate the numbers and search only for those.

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub Highlight_cells

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

With Range("B2:CA" &lastRow).FormatConditions.Add(xlTextString, TextOperator:=xlContains, String:="*miles*")
With .Interior
.Color = RGB(102 255 153)
End With
End With

End Sub
```

But obviously this just highlights anything with the word "miles".

Does anyone have any suggestions? Am I on the right track?

Many thanks in advance.

Edit: Screenshot of sample data
[image]

Comment: Can I see a screenshot of your data?

Comment: We need a better sample of data.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of some example data

Comment: And which fields do you like to condition in the way you asked?

Comment: Is that all in one cell?

Comment: Yes, it all comes through in one cell. Ideally, the entire cell would be highlighted green/yellow/red etc.

Comment: No need for VBA. It is possible with a complex formula. If I show it for `<40 Miles` will you be able to manage for the rest?

Comment: Yes - that would be great, thanks!

Comment: @SJR: You are right. I missed the double number check. tested it limited data. but the logic was correct. Will have to use a different formula. Anyways lot of answers. deleted dmine

Comment: @SiddharthRout - pity, it was an impressively comprehensive answer.

Comment: I can revive it but will have to use a different formula... but do not have the time now... have to head to the gym.. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code, please:

```
Sub Highlight_cells()
Dim rng As Range, sh As Worksheet
Dim cond1 As FormatCondition, cond2 As FormatCondition, cond3 As FormatCondition
Dim lastRow As Long

Set sh = ActiveSheet 'Please put here your sheet
lastRow = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = sh.Range("B2:CA" & lastRow)

rng.FormatConditions.Delete
'<40 miles, green, 40-60 miles, yellow, >60 miles, red.
Set cond1 = rng.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, Formula1:="=VALUE(MID(B2,FIND("" miles"",B2,1)-3,3))<40")
Set cond2 = rng.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, _
    Formula1:="=AND(VALUE(MID(B2,FIND("" miles"",B2,1)-3,3))>=40,VALUE(MID(B2,FIND("" miles"",B2,1)-3,3))<=60)")
Set cond3 = rng.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, Formula1:="=VALUE(MID(B2,FIND("" miles"",B2,1)-3,3))>60")

  With cond1
     .Interior.Color = vbGreen
     .Font.Italic = True
     .SetFirstPriority
  End With       
  With cond2
    .Interior.Color = vbYellow
  End With
  With cond3
    .Font.Color = vbWhite
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Interior.Color = vbRed
  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can even do this with a formula:

`=VALUE(MID(A1,FIND("Distance from last location: ",A1)+LEN("Distance from last location: "),FIND(" miles",A1,FIND("Distance from last location: ",A1))-FIND("Distance from last location: ",A1)-LEN("Distance from last location: ")))`

will extract the distance. The formating then could be done with conditional formatting.

You can also use this formula in the conditional formattig if you don't want an extra column.

This formula could also be easily expanded if you want multiple columns extracted :D I would use column headings where you specify start end end of the value and link them in the formula. (Linebreak would be CHAR(10)). With the right $ References you should have ident formulas for multiple values :D